# multiple row insertion in mysql table through php

Tags: php, mysql

I just installed xampp on my system and created connection and table in mysql using php and i even inserted one row in my table but when i tried to insert multiple rows then the flow directly gone to else part to my customize error message.

My small code is as follows:

```
<?php

include('connection_practice.php');
$insert_query="INSERT INTO student (NAME,ID,ADDRESS,SUBJECT,REMARKS)
               VALUES('AJAY',11,'SILK BOARD','IRO','AVERAGE'),
               VALUES('RITESH',12,'KARTHIK NAGAR','IRO','GOOD'),
               VALUES('SUNNY',13,'HEBBAL','HR MODULE','GOOD'),
               VALUES('HEMAVATHI',14,'HEBBAL','TME','GOOD'),
               VALUES('GURU',15,'HEBBAL','IRO','GOOD'),
               VALUES('SARITHA',16,'HEBBAL','IRO','GOOD'),
               VALUES('NIHAAR',17,'MULTIPLEX','COMPUTERS','AVERAGE')";

if(mysql_query($insert_query,$conn))
{
    echo "8 records added ";
} 
else
{
    echo "record not added ";
}

?>
```

Comment: You only need one `VALUES`

Comment: Whatever happened to error reporting? Don't use mysql methods...EVER. http://nl1.php.net/mysql_query Look at the big red box...pretty hard to miss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO student (NAME, ID, ADDRESS, SUBJECT, REMARKS)
VALUES ('AJAY', 11, 'SILK BOARD', 'IRO', 'AVERAGE'),
('RITESH', 12, 'KARTHIK NAGAR', 'IRO', 'GOOD'), 
('SUNNY', 13, 'HEBBAL', 'HR MODULE', 'GOOD'), 
('HEMAVATHI', 14, 'HEBBAL', 'TME', 'GOOD'),
('GURU', 15, 'HEBBAL', 'IRO', 'GOOD'), 
('SARITHA', 16, 'HEBBAL', 'IRO', 'GOOD'),
('NIHAAR', 17, 'MULTIPLEX', 'COMPUTERS', 'AVERAGE')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)!

Long story short - your code should look as follows:

```
<?php

include('connection_practice.php');
$insert_query="INSERT INTO student (NAME,ID,ADDRESS,SUBJECT,REMARKS)
VALUES('AJAY',11,'SILK BOARD','IRO','AVERAGE'),
('RITESH',12,'KARTHIK NAGAR','IRO','GOOD'),
('SUNNY',13,'HEBBAL','HR MODULE','GOOD'),
('HEMAVATHI',14,'HEBBAL','TME','GOOD'),
('GURU',15,'HEBBAL','IRO','GOOD'),
('SARITHA',16,'HEBBAL','IRO','GOOD'),
('NIHAAR',17,'MULTIPLEX','COMPUTERS','AVERAGE')";

if(mysql_query($insert_query,$conn))
{
echo "8 records added ";
}

else
{
echo "record not added ";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The right sintax is with only one "VALUE" string. something like:

`INSERT INTO student (NAME,ID,ADDRESS,SUBJECT,REMARKS) VALUES
('AJAY',11,'SILK BOARD','IRO','AVERAGE'),
('RITESH',12,'KARTHIK NAGAR','IRO','GOOD'),
('SUNNY',13,'HEBBAL','HR MODULE','GOOD'),
('HEMAVATHI',14,'HEBBAL','TME','GOOD'),`